# Automatically adding .Net code comments

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, comments

Where can I find a Visual Studio plug-in that automatically generates documentation header for methods and properties?

Example the comment to a property could look like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the value of message
/// </summary>
public static string Message        
{
   get
   {
       return message;
   }

   set
   {
       message = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is that comment actually useful to anyone?

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather have no comment than a lame one.  If there isn't a comment for the method, at least you know you might want to go back and add one.

Comment: My sentiment exactly. A colleague of mine is forced to use StyleCop and that damn thing finds errors in anything, even in events' method's header documentation, so she needs some automation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ghostdoc from http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/

Comment: Thank you, the tool is EXACTLY what I needed and it is a very good tool indeed.

Answer (score 4):

[GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/) is the usual suspect.

As another poster mentioned, Visual Studio also does this to an extent by entering 3 '///' (forward slashes) on the line preceding a property/method/class definition.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio does this automatically.  Just position the cursor directly above the method and enter three '/'s
for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcWidgets.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a summary comment
    /// </summary>
    public class Comment
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        /// <param name="birthdate"></param>
        /// <param name="website"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int SomeMethod(string name, DateTime birthdate, Uri website)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then generate an XML comment file and then generate a Help file using SandCastle.

You may have to enable this feature in the Text Editor/C#/Advanced options dialog.

Comment: That's true, but GhostDoc can do some additional things.

Comment: I know about the /// thing, what I need is the filling (= what Ghost Doc does)